# Click on a link based on text

Tags: python, web-scraping

working on python I need your help on how to click on a link based on the text value inside

```
<div class="wn-PreMatchItem wn-PreMatchItem_Selected " style="">
<div class="wn-ClassificationIcon ">
<div class="cis-ClassificationIconSmall cis-ClassificationIconSmall-1 "></div>
</div>
<span>Football</span>
</div>
```

I've tried with this one but it doesn't work at all

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Football']")
```

Can you support me guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are just searching for the element. You need to call `.click()` to actually click it:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Football']").click()
```

If that doesn't work, you can try to click one of the `div` elements instead.